# Regular expression to select group of text/bunch of lines based on specific line of text

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, capture-group

I have the text in below format

```
Scenario: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Given sed do eiusmod tempor
When Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
Then In voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla

@Sprint4 @543fsdf
Scenario: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Given sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
When Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
Then In voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla

@Sprint1 @345277
Scenario: Sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt returned correct singular message
Given sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
And Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit  
When Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
Then quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur

@Sprint1 @xyz1234
Scenario: At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis
Given sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
And Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit  
When Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
Then quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur
```

I want to select whole scenario based on a line of text in it.

For eg.

based on the line 'Given sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'

I want the second scenario

```
Scenario: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Given sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
When Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
Then In voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
```

, also the third and fourth scenario - but not the first one

I am trying

```
Scenario[\s\S]*?Given sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua[\s\S]*?(?=(@|Scenario))
```

But that gives me first and second scenarios together and third but no fourth scenario. I tried other patterns as well but not a lot of success. Help?

Comment: Split your text by scenarii (by blocks) and filter the blocks.

Comment: So you want the three lines starting with 'Given', 'When' and 'Then'? Or you just don't want the first Scenario (which doesn't have @)

Comment: Not really. I want everything starting with Scenario: till end of that block.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your Scenario always begin on a new line, you can use look-behind to search for that, and you can use look-aheat to search for whitespace followed by `@` or end of the string to capture the end of a matched block. So, for your example:

```
(?<=\s)Scenario.*?[\r\n]+Given sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua[\r\n]+.*?(?=\s+@|\s*$)
```

You didn't specify what language are you using so you'll have to do the set up, but from options (if not default) you need to choose that dot matches line breaks, and that `^` and `$` don't match line breaks but rather the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if will help, but what I did was to match all lines with @ until the end of line. So you could replace that by null, if this is the case.

```
(@\V+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iCt1j2/1